# How can i run the c# clr function in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm new in c# want to write simple clr function in c# and use that in sql server,for that purpose write this function in visual studio:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]

    public static SqlString behzad()
    {
        var name = "behzad";
        var family = "razzaqi";
        return new SqlString (name+" "+family);
    }
}
```

so register that in sql server with this way:

```
use [SAMPLE]
CREATE ASSEMBLY testbehzad
   FROM 'e:\TestScript.dll'
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE; 
GO
```

now how can i use behzad function in sql server?thanks

Comment: you can find tons of examples in web. just google it.

Comment: First think if that's really needed? Why cannot you do the stuff in sql directly!?